# Trying to correct an improperly formatted JSON string using python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm trying to use any combination of the **Python** "**re**" library and python slice to correct this improperly formatted JSON string that Kafka is giving us on HDFS using Cloudera's Hadoop distribution.

incorrect json:

```
{"json_data":"{"table":"TEST.FUBAR","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848","current_ts":"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002","pos":"1111","after":{"COL1":949494949494949494,"COL2":99,"COL3":2,"COL4":"            99999","COL5":9999999,"COL6":90,"COL7":42478,"COL8":"I","COL9":null,"COL10":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL11":null,"COL12":null,"COL13":null,"COL14":"x222263 ","COL15":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL16":"x222263 ","COL17":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL18":"2020-09-10 00:00:00","COL19":"A","COL20":"A","COL21":0,"COL22":null,"COL23":"2019-03-14 15:33:47","COL24":2,"COL25":2,"COL26":"R","COL27":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL28":"  ","COL29":"PBU67H   ","COL30":"            20000","COL31":2,"COL32":null}}"}
```

**NOTE:** the double quotes near the beginning tag "**json_data**":***"***{ and the double quotes near the end on "**null**}}**"**} are actually the only things wrong that need to be removed (I've tested it without the extra quotes)

valid and correct json:

```
{"json_data":{"table":"TEST.FUBAR","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848","current_ts":"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002","pos":"1111","after":{"COL1":949494949494949494,"COL2":99,"COL3":2,"COL4":"            99999","COL5":9999999,"COL6":90,"COL7":42478,"COL8":"I","COL9":null,"COL10":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL11":null,"COL12":null,"COL13":null,"COL14":"x222263 ","COL15":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL16":"x222263 ","COL17":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL18":"2020-09-10 00:00:00","COL19":"A","COL20":"A","COL21":0,"COL22":null,"COL23":"2019-03-14 15:33:47","COL24":2,"COL25":2,"COL26":"R","COL27":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL28":"  ","COL29":"PBU67H   ","COL30":"            20000","COL31":2,"COL32":null}}}
```

I have between **40,000 to 60,000 records** I would need to read thru per hour using Pyspark and the Infrastructure team says it's on me to fix.

Is there a quick and dirty way using python to read all the strings and remove the double quotes near the beginning and near the end?

Comment: If the offending prefix/trailer are always the same, you could just strip them like `loads(bad_json[14:-3])`. Better yet, convince the lazy devops to fix that - that's clearly their fault.

Comment: Using the strip method was definitely my first go to but not all the JSON strings are the same length or have the same number of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the string offered I do suggest you stick with `re` a regex such as:

```
'(?<=:|\})(")(?=\}|\{)'
```

Should do the trick. Since the double quotes that are not needed follow closing blackets or a colon and preced opening or closing brackets.

```
import re
import json

string = '{"json_data":"{"table":"TEST.FUBAR","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848","current_ts":"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002","pos":"1111","after":{"COL1":949494949494949494,"COL2":99,"COL3":2,"COL4":"            99999","COL5":9999999,"COL6":90,"COL7":42478,"COL8":"I","COL9":null,"COL10":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL11":null,"COL12":null,"COL13":null,"COL14":"x222263 ","COL15":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL16":"x222263 ","COL17":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL18":"2020-09-10 00:00:00","COL19":"A","COL20":"A","COL21":0,"COL22":null,"COL23":"2019-03-14 15:33:47","COL24":2,"COL25":2,"COL26":"R","COL27":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL28":"  ","COL29":"PBU67H   ","COL30":"            20000","COL31":2,"COL32":null}"}}'

trimmed_string = re.sub('(?<=:|\})(")(?=\}|\{)', '', string)

data = json.loads(trimmed_string)
```

Results:

```
{'json_data': {'table': 'TEST.FUBAR', 'op_type': 'I', 'op_ts': '2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848','current_ts': '2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002', 'pos': '1111', 'after': {'COL1': 949494949494949494, 'COL2': 99, 'COL3': 2, 'COL4': '            99999', 'COL5': 9999999, 'COL6': 90, 'COL7':42478, 'COL8': 'I', 'COL9': None, 'COL10': '2019-03-14 15:33:49', 'COL11': None, 'COL12': None, 'COL13': None, 'COL14': 'x222263 ', 'COL15': '2019-03-14 15:33:49', 'COL16': 'x222263 ', 'COL17': '2019-03-14 15:33:49', 'COL18': '2020-09-10 00:00:00', 'COL19': 'A', 'COL20': 'A', 'COL21': 0, 'COL22': None, 'COL23': '2019-03-14 15:33:47', 'COL24': 2, 'COL25': 2, 'COL26': 'R', 'COL27': '2019-03-14 15:33:49', 'COL28': '  ', 'COL29': 'PBU67H   ', 'COL30': '20000', 'COL31': 2, 'COL32': None}}}
```